# Filter timeseries data in Postgresql to return previous record and following records

Tags: postgresql

I have a large table containing sensor readings, and a corresponding staging table with new readings.

I am trying to filter the records I get from the main table so as to get only the relevant information for calculating the deltas.

A self-contained, simplified example which:

- creates dummy data for sensors 1 to 6 for the last seven days, in the main table.
- creates new sensor data for sensors 3 to 5, for the last three days, in staging.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_sensor_reading;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stg_sensor_reading;
    CREATE TABLE tb_sensor_reading(
        sensor_id INTEGER
        , ts_reading TIMESTAMP
        , reading_value NUMERIC(8, 3)
    );
    CREATE TABLE stg_sensor_reading AS TABLE tb_sensor_reading WITH NO DATA;
    
    SELECT * FROM stg_sensor_reading;
    
    INSERT INTO tb_sensor_reading( 
         sensor_id 
         , ts_reading 
         , reading_value 
    ) 
    SELECT 
        generated_sensor_id 
        , generated_ts_reading 
        -- readings delta may vary between +25 and +49.9 between each reading 
        , EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM generated_ts_reading) / (3600 * 6 / 25) 
            - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days') / (3600 * 6 / 25) 
            + RANDOM()*24.9
    FROM 
        GENERATE_SERIES(1,6) AS generated_sensor_id 
        , GENERATE_SERIES( 
            NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days', NOW(), INTERVAL '6 hours' 
        ) AS generated_ts_reading 
    ; 
    -- generate dummy records in stg_reading 
    INSERT INTO stg_sensor_reading( 
         sensor_id 
         , ts_reading 
         , reading_value 
    ) 
    SELECT 
        generated_sensor_id 
        , generated_ts_reading 
        , EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM generated_ts_reading) / (3600 * 6 / 25) 
          - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days') / (3600 * 6 / 25) 
          + RANDOM()*24.9 
    FROM 
        GENERATE_SERIES(3, 5) AS generated_sensor_id 
        , GENERATE_SERIES( 
            NOW() - INTERVAL '3 days'
            , NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days'
            , INTERVAL '6 hours' 
        ) AS generated_ts_reading 
    ;
    SELECT * FROM tb_sensor_reading LIMIT 5 ;
```

### Result

```
SELECT * FROM tb_sensor_reading LIMIT 5;

     sensor_id |         ts_reading         | reading_value
    -----------+----------------------------+---------------
             1 | 2022-01-03 13:25:16.417613 |         7.154
             1 | 2022-01-03 19:25:16.417613 |        46.736
             1 | 2022-01-04 01:25:16.417613 |        73.835
             1 | 2022-01-04 07:25:16.417613 |        89.147
             1 | 2022-01-04 13:25:16.417613 |       105.444
(5 rows) 

 SELECT * FROM stg_sensor_reading ;
 sensor_id |         ts_reading         | reading_value
-----------+----------------------------+---------------
         3 | 2022-01-07 18:40:19.978908 |       406.839
         3 | 2022-01-08 00:40:19.978908 |       435.935
         3 | 2022-01-08 06:40:19.978908 |       454.385
         3 | 2022-01-08 12:40:19.978908 |       495.853
         3 | 2022-01-08 18:40:19.978908 |       516.214
         4 | 2022-01-07 18:40:19.978908 |       410.096
         4 | 2022-01-08 00:40:19.978908 |       442.941
         4 | 2022-01-08 06:40:19.978908 |       462.816
         4 | 2022-01-08 12:40:19.978908 |       496.893
         4 | 2022-01-08 18:40:19.978908 |       517.247
         5 | 2022-01-07 18:40:19.978908 |       419.876
         5 | 2022-01-08 00:40:19.978908 |       425.990
         5 | 2022-01-08 06:40:19.978908 |       464.086
         5 | 2022-01-08 12:40:19.978908 |       486.731
         5 | 2022-01-08 18:40:19.978908 |       515.454
(15 rows)
```

I am trying to select the records from tb_sensor_readings to return:

- ✅ only the sensor_id which are present in stg_sensor_reading :

```
SELECT * FROM tb_sensor_reading
WHERE sensor_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT sensor_id from stg_sensor_reading
)
ORDER BY sensor_id, ts_reading

LIMIT 5;

 sensor_id |         ts_reading         | reading_value
-----------+----------------------------+---------------
         3 | 2022-01-03 13:25:16.417613 |        24.669
         3 | 2022-01-03 19:25:16.417613 |        48.384
         3 | 2022-01-04 01:25:16.417613 |        56.889
         3 | 2022-01-04 07:25:16.417613 |        95.980
         3 | 2022-01-04 13:25:16.417613 |       120.536
```

- ❌ only the previous record and the following records for each sensor_id, i.e. in pseudo code:

  ```
  MAX(tb_sensor_reading.ts_reading) < MIN(stg_sensor_reading.ts_reading)
  OR tb_sensor_reading.ts_reading > MIN(stg_sensor_reading.ts_reading)
  ON tb_sensor_reading.sensor_id = stg_sensor_reading. sensor_id
  ```

How can I :

- return the correct series for each sensor, even though their minimum timestamp differ greatly between one another ?
- include the previous record with same sensor_id in the filter ?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Try `lag` and `lead`

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your comment. I have managed to find a solution that uses DISTINCT ON, not sure however if that performs well compared to LAG function for this kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

I could select the desired rows from tb_reading by using a UNION operator.

- The first query gets the last reading for each
  sensor_id from tb_reading, which occured prior to the first of the new readings.
- The second subquery returns the readings from tb_sensor_reading, for each sensor_id, which happened during the same time period of the readings available in the staging table.
- the WHERE tb.sensor_id = stg.sensor_id is not worth the cost if the role of the query is to limit the number of rows from which to calculate the deltas.

```
(SELECT -- most recent previous reading for each sensor_id
    DISTINCT ON (sensor_id)
    sensor_id
    , ts_reading
    , reading_value
    FROM
      tb_sensor_reading tb
    WHERE sensor_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sensor_id FROM stg_sensor_reading)
       AND ts_reading < ALL(
           SELECT MIN(ts_reading)
           FROM stg_sensor_reading stg
           WHERE tb.sensor_id = stg.sensor_id
    ) ORDER BY sensor_id, ts_reading DESC
  
)
UNION
    SELECT -- all readings that happened in the same period than stg
      sensor_id
      , ts_reading
      , reading_value
    FROM tb_sensor_reading tb
    WHERE
       sensor_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sensor_id FROM stg_sensor_reading)
       AND ts_reading >= ALL(
          SELECT MIN(ts_reading)
          FROM stg_sensor_reading stg
          WHERE tb.sensor_id = stg.sensor_id
        )
       AND ts_reading <= ALL(
          SELECT MAX(ts_reading)
          FROM stg_sensor_reading stg
          WHERE tb.sensor_id = stg.sensor_id
        )
    ORDER BY sensor_id, ts_reading DESC ;
```

### result

```
 sensor_id |         ts_reading         | reading_value
-----------+----------------------------+---------------
         3 | 2022-01-08 18:40:19.973512 |       514.387
         3 | 2022-01-08 12:40:19.973512 |       490.200
         3 | 2022-01-08 06:40:19.973512 |       468.323
         3 | 2022-01-08 00:40:19.973512 |       438.597
         3 | 2022-01-07 18:40:19.973512 |       420.665
         4 | 2022-01-08 18:40:19.973512 |       524.803
         4 | 2022-01-08 12:40:19.973512 |       497.348
         4 | 2022-01-08 06:40:19.973512 |       468.300
         4 | 2022-01-08 00:40:19.973512 |       430.468
         4 | 2022-01-07 18:40:19.973512 |       411.204
         5 | 2022-01-08 18:40:19.973512 |       504.969
         5 | 2022-01-08 12:40:19.973512 |       482.629
         5 | 2022-01-08 06:40:19.973512 |       473.075
         5 | 2022-01-08 00:40:19.973512 |       432.396
         5 | 2022-01-07 18:40:19.973512 |       405.156
(15 rows)
```